STM32F103 can I connect the BOOT0 pin to a second input pin so I can re-use the line?
I'm making a project with multiple STM32F103 connected to a central MCU. I want to use the MCU to also program the STMs so I don't have to do it manually, therefore I'm connecting it via 4 lines: power, RX, TX, and BOOT0.
I'm wondering if I can re-use the BOOT0 line if I connect it in parallel to a separate input pin of the STM32? According to the manual the BOOT0 is read at startup/awake once and that's about it. Is there any downside I'm not seeing?

The BOOT0 pin is an input.
If you want, you can connect the output of another MCU to multiple input pins on the sub-MCU, such as BOOT0 and most GPIO pins.
